# How to still have space-between when middle element wraps

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

here is a demo i've created: https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-angular-material-fgconc

steps to reproduce:

1. "Open in New Window" and drag it to full size.
2. drag right border and make window smaller.
3. when the middle element starts wrapping -> problem

When it starts wrapping the space left is gone and all space is on the right.

How can I have the same space "left and right" when the middle element wraps?

---

@Akber Iqbal 's suggestion `style="text-align:center"` already does a good job.

#### How ever is it possible to have the elements wrap in the below style (green)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using your existing [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-angular-material-fgconc?file=app%2Fapp.component.html), make one change in your app.component.html, just add: **style="text-align:center"** to the 2nd `div`

Final **app.component.html** to be:

```
<div fxLayout = "row nowrap" fxLayoutAlign = "space-evenly center">
  <img fxFlex="0 0 auto" fxFlexAlign="center" style="height: 3em" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png">

  <div fxLayout = "row wrap" fxFlex = "0 1 auto" style="text-align:center">
  <app-many-buttons [N]="10"></app-many-buttons>
  </div>

  <div fxLayout = "row nowrap" fxFlex = "0 0 auto">
      <button mat-button class="materialIconButton">lol_1</button>

      <button mat-button class="materialIconButton">lol_1</button>

      <button mat-button class="materialIconButton">lol_1</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that works, thank you. Is there a way that the wrapping 2. 3. (and so on) row-elements start directly under the first row element. Ill add an image if unclear.

Comment: please add an image... do you mean that one button on each row ?

Comment: added a foto to my question

Comment: I don't think that we can get it for a free flowing CSS [means that the screen can get as big or as small as we want]... as a workaround, we can however restrict that a particular row to to have X number of buttons and then once the width decreases, we decrease the number of buttons that can exist...

Comment: thank you for your help so far. You solution already improved my problem significantly. Ill wait a little bit for another solution. And then could mark this as answer.

Comment: you got it, Thanks :)